# How to correct node Recursive process.nextTick?

Tags: node.js, bower

I have an error when a launch `bower install`

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
  throw err;
        ^
```

**System info:

Bower version: 1.2.4 
Node version: 0.10.17

OS: Linux 3.5.0-39-generic ia32 (UBUNTU)**

How can resolve this, without change my bower.json ?
my bower.json look like

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-unstable": "~1.1.4",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.5",
    "angular-resource": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-complete": "*",
    "jquery": ">=1.8",
    "bootstrap": "~2.3.1",
    "bootstrap-js": "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip",
      "angular-bootstrap": "~0.3",
    "jquery.scrollTo": "1.4.4",
    "ng-translate": "https://github.com/nezo/ng-translate/archive/master.zip",
    "ngUpload": "*",
    "less.js": "1.3.3",
    "Chart.js": "*",
    "carouFredSel": "https://raw.github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel/master/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js",
    "angular-ui": "0.4.0",
    "jquery-file-upload": "*",
    "jquery-ui": "*",
      "spin.js": "~1.3",
    "OpenLayers-2.12": "http://openlayers.org/download/OpenLayers-2.12.zip",
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by `"OpenLayers-2.12"`, though it seems to be only be an issue with the `.zip`. Try instead with the `.tar.gz`:

```
"OpenLayers-2.12": "http://openlayers.org/download/OpenLayers-2.12.tar.gz"
```

---

Also, the URL for `bootstrap.zip` moved with the recent release of Bootstrap 3.

```
"bootstrap-js": "http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/bootstrap.zip"
```